# Problem showing table with Javascript condition

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc

I have a Sprinv MVC Controller, when I submit a form I return the same page but with some objects and a String called `hidden` that has the value False. When I submit the form I have a `window.onload` function that gets the value of the this string and checks if it has the string value "false" to display 3 divs that were hidden but they didn't.

I'm struggling where is the problem because I tried a lot of things.

This is my HTML Form.

```
          <form class="forms-sample" action="Buscar.do" method="POST" >
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>client:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="identificador" placeholder="DNI/NIF">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-gradient-primary btn-gradient-aj mr-2">Obtenir Autoritzacions</button>
          </form>
```

And here's the javascript code.

```
  <script>
  window.onload = function showTable() {
        var z = ${hidden}
        if(z.localeCompare("false") == 0){
            var x = document.getElementById("Prueba");
            var x2 = document.getElementById("Prueba2");
            var x3 = document.getElementById("Prueba3");
                x.style.display = "block";
                x2.style.display = "block";
                x3.style.display = "block";
        }


    }
</script>
```

I checked with `innerHTML` and the value Im getting is false so they localeCompare should do the If condition, I think the problem is in the if because i tried withouth the if and it works. Also I didnt post the divs Prueba/Prueba2/Prueba3 becasue they're not important, i mean they could be only a text.

**SOLVED**
I created a input type hidden with that the MVC controller returns and get it by javascript with `z = document.getElementById('form1').elements[1].value` . Thanks to @kemicofa for the tip.

Comment: If this is a copy paste of your actual javascript code, then you'll surely have an error in your console. `var z = ${hidden}` is not valid javascript.

Comment: So if I'm getting the String from the Spring Mcv controller how can I get it into the variable to compare in javascript @kemicofa

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Spring, but from the syntax in your js code, I'm assuming it replaces things with ${} with their Spring variables. I know with PHP or Handlebars, you need to provide the quotes yourself, so try replacing ${hidden} with "${hidden}".

Answer (score 0):

The spring expression needs to be within single quotes;

**var z = '${hidden}';**